# How to install .NET framework 4.0 only

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

is it possible to install only the .NET 4.0 Framework only?

I do not want 2.0 or 3.5 Framework on my system.

Thanks.

Comment: Or even instructions on uninstalling 2.0 or 3.5 would be great.

Comment: Mythje, How can I do it?

Comment: Its just listed in the uninstall a program list

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you want to install .NET 4.0 only?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall any previous .NETs you might have (Control Panel ...) then get 4.0 from here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en and install it. See if your OS is supported.